# Swift/SpriteKit How to check whether SKNode instance is not nil

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, option-type

Why does the following code not work?

```
if let helloNode: SKNode = self.childNodeWithName("helloNode")! { ... }
```

self.childNodeWithName("helloNode") returns SKNode?.

! unwraps the return value to SKNode.
helloNode captures SKNode.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to unwrap it.

```
if let helloNode: SKNode = self.childNodeWithName("helloNode") { ... }
```

The point of `if let` is to see if the value is not nil before you enter the block. If you unwrap it in the 'if let' statement it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "!". It is not appropriate in an "if let .." context. "If let ..." already unwraps the value.